# react.js-same component with different props passed

Tags: reactjs

i have a project to build a website , i was stuck in a problem
    I have a parent component that has in his state two empty arrays(Top-rated Movies, popular movies), and I am fetching data from API end store it in the arrays.
    I have a child component(movie) that I passed props to him from a parent, and I able to show the data for
    a popular movie. the question is how do i use the same component(movie) but with different props(top-rated movies props )?
those are the component. is there any way to use the component
again without create a new component with different props, and 
not just in their but in different places in the website

```
Home.js

const baseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie';
const baseImgUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300';

export class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            topRatedMovies: null,
            popularMovies: null,
            isLoading: false
        }
        this.checkIfDataAvailable = this.checkIfDataAvailable.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const queryPopularMovies = `/popular?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&video=true`;
        const queryTopRated = `/top_rated/?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&video=true`;

        const responsePopularMovies = await axios.get(baseUrl + queryPopularMovies)
        const responseTopRated = await axios.get(baseUrl + queryTopRated)

        this.setState({
            topRatedMovies: responseTopRated.data.results,
            popularMovies: responsePopularMovies.data.results
        })
    }

    checkIfDataAvailable() {
        if(this.state.popularMovies) {
            return (
                    <Row>
                        {this.state.popularMovies.map(movie =>
                            <Col sm="3">
                                <Movie 
                                    key={movie.id}
                                    title={movie.title}
                                    src={`${baseImgUrl}/${movie.poster_path}`}
                                />
                            </Col>    
                        )}
                    </Row>        
            )
        } else {
            console.log('Is Loading....')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                <div className="Home-header">
                    <div className="Home-headline">
                        <Container fluid>
                            <h1 className="Home-headline__primary">Welcome To Movie Hunter Website</h1>
                            <p className="Home-headline__secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut suscipit condimentum ligula, et ultricies lectus ligula, et ultricies lectus ligula, et ultricies lectus.</p>
                            <Button className="Home-headline-button">Into the Site</Button>
                        </Container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="Home-main">
                    <Container>
                        <h2 className="Home-main-primary">Popular Movies</h2>
                            {this.checkIfDataAvailable()} 
                    </Container>

                    <Container>
                        <h2 className="Home-main-primary">Top Rated Movies</h2>
                    </Container>
                </div>                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Movie.js

export class Movie extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Movie">
                    <Card className="Movie-Card">
                        <CardImg className="Card-Img"  src={this.props.src} alt={this.props.title}></CardImg>
                        <CardBody>
                            <CardTitle>{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
                            <Button>Buy Ticket </Button>
                            <i className="em em-black_heart mx-2" aria-role="presentation" aria-label="BLACK HEART"></i>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Movie
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: i posted it, if you cant check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make your `checkIfDataAvailable` function accept some parameters and then you are good to go.

```js
checkIfDataAvailable(movies) {
        if(movies.length) {
            return (
                    <Row>
                        {movies.map(movie =>
                            <Col sm="3">
                                <Movie 
                                    key={movie.id}
                                    title={movie.title}
                                    src={`${baseImgUrl}/${movie.poster_path}`}
                                />
                            </Col>    
                        )}
                    </Row>        
            )
        } else {
            console.log('Is Loading....')
        }
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                <div className="Home-header">
                    <div className="Home-headline">
                        <Container fluid>
                            <h1 className="Home-headline__primary">Welcome To Movie Hunter Website</h1>
                            <p className="Home-headline__secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut suscipit condimentum ligula, et ultricies lectus ligula, et ultricies lectus ligula, et ultricies lectus.</p>
                            <Button className="Home-headline-button">Into the Site</Button>
                        </Container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="Home-main">
                    <Container>
                        <h2 className="Home-main-primary">Popular Movies</h2>
                            {this.checkIfDataAvailable(this.state.popularMovies)} 
                    </Container>

                    <Container>
                        <h2 className="Home-main-primary">Top Rated Movies</h2>
                         {this.checkIfDataAvailable(this.state.topRatedMovies)}
                    </Container>
                </div>                
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I have another problem with the key . its always says that key should be unique, and I use the id that I get from the API as key, but still its throw this key problem

Comment: You can use combination of both title and movie id to create key